# Do I need to keep Steam mobile open to get sale messages?

Tags: steam, steam-mobile

I accidentally launched Steam's mobile app the other day, and it gave me a chance to register for push notifications about ongoing sales. Thing is, there are quite a few sales going on right now, and I haven't been getting any notifications. Do I need to keep the application open in the background in order to get these notifications?

By keeping the application open, I mean this:
[image]

Comment: Well, sort of hard for an application to receive notifications if it's not running.

Comment: @fbueckert Actually, I've had a chance to develop for the Windows Phone 7 (of all things), and over there there's no need for an application to be running in order to receive notifications. I have no idea if that holds true for Android, though.

Comment: Huh.  Didn't know that.  The more you know...

Comment: I think this belongs on android.SE, but apparently the mod who reviewed my flag disagrees.  It's a question purely about the functionality of the application notifications (which is a system-level thing) and isn't gaming-related at all beyond the purpose of the app itself.

Comment: @Shinrai I could indeed be lacking in my Android education, but I have plenty of apps on my phone that supply notifications, and none of them asked me for permission in such a direct manner, nor do they have a "lurk in the background" mode. Seeing how this specific application doesn't seem to be coughing up notifications, I ask.

Comment: @Aubergine - No, it's a great question, I just think it'd get better answers over there.

Comment: @Aubergine - The reason most apps don't ask for permission is that most of them use pull notification. This means that you generally have control over when and if they check for notification. With push notifications, you have less control over when the notification comes in, so most apps with push will ask first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Steam app starts itself up whenever it has something to tell me. It would make sense that it wouldn't have to be open to receive a notification. The difference between push and pull notifications is where they originate from. In a pull notification, the app goes out and checks with the server to see if there is anything new. With a push notification, the server sends out a message when there is something new. This would seem to indicate that you wouldn't necessarily have to have the app open for you to be able to receive a push notification.

Comment: I've been noticing the same, but only in the last few days. I could never be sure that I didn't forget it open, though, so it's good to have some corroboration.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to always do it, but I'm sure I didn't accidentally leave it open, as I never really open it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so. I received the same offer, accepted, and then promptly turned off the application. I have not received any other notifications from the Steam app.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'll just leave it open and see what happens, then.